# Moderators ignoring flags

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, flagging, moderation

For some reason the moderators have ignored my recent flags. My flags have not been declined, deemed helpful, etc. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mariano is right](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6814/23137). Nobody is ignoring your flags.

However, this is because nobody can *see* your flags any more unless they look directly at the flag history of a post and even then that's just a record of your flag, not an actionable thing.

You had a large number of flags declined (more than were found helpful). As a result, your flags are no longer shown to moderators and cannot be acted on either way.

At the moment there's unfortunately no way for you to recover from that.

Comment: Wow, really? There's no return from flag weight zero?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Apparently not. In principle that makes sense - if someone's raising a lot of bad flags, we kind of want them to stop.  On the other hand, people can and do learn to flag better. Recovering from zero flag weight would probably require raising flags that can be seen and evaluated, which sort of defeats the purpose of zero flag weight. So I'm not sure right off the bat how best to approach changing this behaviour or if it should be changed.

Comment: Hmm. I think that one should use the review page to review automatically raised flags or so. Maybe that way to allow an increase in flag weight... but that sounds pretty impossible, almost all automatic flags are invalidated (not all, but the vast majority).

Comment: @AdamLear Wasn't flagging stuff that other users flag as well a way to recover flag weight?

Comment: @Mad: that's been theorized - I don't know if anyone's actually been in a position to *test* it though.

Comment: This needs to be fixed.

Comment: Adam, why was I pinged now when you edited the comment?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Huh, no idea! I didn't think we notified on comment edits. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, we do, but I'm not even mentioned in that comment! There's a bug report for ya!

Answer (score 10):

We do not immediately handle all flags.

No one is *ignoring your flags*.

Answer (score 5):

Often when flagging it is the case that there are several open flags on the same post.

Moderators cannot clear just one flag, even if they acted according to the suggestion in the flag. In such cases moderators often keep the flags open in order to decide how to clear them.

(*Note:* I have never been a moderator, but I sure as hell flagged a lot. Roughly 950 flags - 780 accepted (and 120 disputed, most of which are invalidations).)